# pick a random value with picker

Tags: ios, random, uipickerview

I am new to developing and im just trying to have picker with a list of values. I also want to have a button under the picker that will choose a random value in the picker. With the animation and all.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pick a random row using one of [arc4random](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/arc4random.3.html) functions.

Personally I suggest         arc4random_uniform().

Then simply
 use [selectRow:inComponent:animated:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPickerView/selectRow%3ainComponent%3aanimated%3a) to select the row, and set animated to YES.

code bellow:

```
NSInteger component = arc4random_uniform([picker numberOfComponents]);
NSInteger row = arc4random_uniform([picker numberOfRowsInComponent:component]);

[picker selectRow:row inComponent:component animated:YES];
```